# Gulp watch does nothing

Tags: javascript, gulp

Following [this tutorial](http://codehangar.io/gulp-sass/), I've setup a basic gulp config along with a .scss file that I want compiled into `.css` using gulp-sass. When I run gulp watch from the console, the watch task register fine, but nothing happens when I edit the `.scss` file, and I can't figure out why.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');  
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

//style paths
var sassFiles = 'assets/styles/sass/**/*.scss',  
    cssDest = 'assets/styles/css/';

gulp.task('styles', function(){  
    gulp.src(sassFiles)
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {  
    gulp.watch('sassFiles',['styles']);
});
```

**terminal output:**

```
shooshte@M:~/Webpages/CV2$ gulp watch
[20:38:40] Using gulpfile ~/Webpages/CV2/gulpfile.js
[20:38:40] Starting 'watch'...
[20:38:40] Finished 'watch' after 5.37 ms
```

Comment: Could you try remove simple quotes from `'sassFiles'` value inside `gulp.watch` call ?

Comment: What is the directory structure of your project? Edit: it seems Fabien Thourand has the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were passing `'sassFiles'` (as a string) and not the `sassFiles` variable.

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {  
    gulp.watch(sassFiles,['styles']); // Removed '' around sassFiles 
});
```

I also noticed you are passing the sassFiles variable into your styles task. I'm a bit foggy but I don't think this works and further more It may, as suggested, indicate a poor directory structure.

The suggested methods for [how to structure a sass project](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project) vary, but all share one common factor. They suggest breaking up your sass into partials prefixed with an underscore

```
/styles
  application.scss
  _footer.scss
  _header.scss
  _sidebar.scss
```

And then importing them all into a single top level scss file. application.scss

```
@import "footer";
@import "header";
@import "sidebar";
```

You can then just tell the styles task to compile `application.scss` and all of the files referenced as imports will get pulled in automatically.

```
gulp.task('styles', function(){  
    gulp.src('assets/styles/sass/application.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(cssDest));
});
```